# purpose of @property in objective c

Tags: objective-c, properties

Look a the below code;

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController
{
     int age;
     UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain ) int age;
@property (nonatomic , retain ) UIPopoverController *popoverController;

@end
```

`@property (nonatomic , retain ) int age` defines getters and setters for `int age;`
and `@synthesizing` them in implemetation gives the autogenerated implementation of the getter and setter.

what i dont understand is about the second one. what methods does the second property (`@property (nonatomic , retain ) UIPopoverController *popoverController;`) generate? (:

i have seen lot of programs that use `@property` with objects apart from int, string etc;

can any guide me to a proper tutorial about this.

Thanks in advance.  (also can somebody tell me how to accept answers on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to advise anything better then [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) (at least you should start with reading it).

```
@property (nonatomic , retain ) int age;
```

Is really supposed to declare setter/getter methods for age ivar, but that line will give compiler error as you can't declare property with retain attribute for non-object types (see docs for more details)

```
@property (nonatomic , retain ) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

This line does not differ much from the 1st one - it also declares setter and getter methods for popoverController ivar, and automatically synthesized setter will retain popoverController it gets

Answer (score 2):

If you have this:

```
@property (nonatomic , retain ) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

the methods generated by @synthesize will be something like:

```
-(UIPopoverController*) popoverController
{
    return popoverController;
}

-(void) setPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*) newValue
{
    [newValue retain];
    [popoverController release];
    popoverController = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@synthesize` always creates the accessors. In your case:

```
- (void) setPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)value;
- (UIPopoverController *) popoverController;
```